# Geometry Nodes' points tracked to camera (Outdated)

Tags: node-editor, procedural, geometry-nodes

I'm pretty new to Geometry Nodes, and I wanted to have a plane with points that were constantly tracked to an object. In this case I wanted to **billboard** them to the camera.
I know how to do it with particles and constraints, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in geometry nodes.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243319/2214

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

tutorial:
https://youtu.be/DUy3SETz9u8

for newer GN versions (up to 3.3)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "Attribute Vector" node doesn't exist in Blender 3.1.

Comment: @Chris OP is not version specific, why don't update answer or add another answer for current version?

Comment: updated my answer