Change UV position and rotation based on camera angle
In my pursuit of detailing a vast landscape, I was following the tutorial by Martin Klekner about the 2D translation of a 3D object in the 'Fake Large-scale Forests' tutorial.
Since this only allows the viewer to see one side, I was wondering if this could be improved by using a sprite-like approach.
A geometry node setup could create a plane that always faces the active camera and show a detailed 3D model that was rendered from different angles and combined in a 4 by 4 or 6 by 6 grid (or any numbered grid), it could choose the best image based on the camera position.
I was wondering if geometry nodes can do this:

Create a plane that has a certain height, width and shader.
Find the position of the active camera and make the plane always face it.
Offset the UV's based on the number of sprites in the texture map and the camera position.
Create a second plane that always faces the light source, choose the correct angle based on the light source location. This could be invisible for the rendered image, but throws a more correct shadow.

Hopefully this could improve the 3D projection on a 2D plane and make much faster and more detailed renders, even if the camera is higher.
Is this even possible using geometry nodes and would this approach be beneficial?

Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/243305/145249

please focus on one question. This is one rule here. You may open as many questions as you want.
